# How can I test that my code does not open more than 50 request connections at a time in my c# .net core project?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am doing data mining and in theory my code should do batches of 50 requests, run the specific batch in parallel but be blocking for the batch to finish.

I need to ensure that it is actually running as expected and not opening more than 50 outgoing connections - but I have no idea how to get access to that information, and continuously monitor it for me to write an automated test with.

I am not even sure that I am creating an outgoing request for any batch in my tests since I am mocking my http client like so:

```
protected HttpClient httpClient;
protected Mock<HttpMessageHandlerFake> fakeHttpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandlerFake> { CallBase = true };
httpClient = new HttpClient(fakeHttpMessageHandler.Object);



protected void MockHttpResponse(string url, string mockedResponse)
{
    fakeHttpMessageHandler.Setup(f => f.Send(It.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(x => x.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri == url))).Returns(new HttpResponseMessage
    {
         StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
         Content = new StringContent(mockedResponse)
    });
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated - I am just going to spin up my own separate server on my local machine and return canned responses with 1 second delays to ensure i am not going over my open connection limit and throwing an exception.. but still this is manual testing.

Comment: I’m not sure theres enough code there to help. What does your test look like?

Comment: i have no test for open connections limit, since i dont know where to start :D

Answer (score 0):

Craig, I suppose you use `moq` library?

Give a try with `.Callback(() => Interlocked.Increment(ref calls));`

e.g., in your class:

```
private int calls = 0;
public int Calls {get {return Interlocked.Read(ref calls);}}

protected void MockHttpResponse(string url, string mockedResponse)
{
        fakeHttpMessageHandler.Setup(f => f.Send(It.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(x => x.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri == url))).Returns(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
             StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
             Content = new StringContent(mockedResponse)
        }).Callback(() => Interlocked.Increment(ref calls));
    }
```

Comment: that is a very, very interesting answer however that gets me the total and not how many are actually open at any given time no?

Comment: I am not sure you can get the number of active connections from httpclient in .net core, but you can limit the max connections per server endpoint by using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Http_HttpClientHandler_MaxConnectionsPerServer     Could you reveal more of you code? Maybe there is another solution to test your batch processing